# WPF UserControl Inheritance & Style

Tags: wpf, inheritance, user-controls

I have the following Problem: I create a custom control which inherits from an already existing one, i.e.

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public Boolean AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

This works without problem, but if I try to Style the element it doesn't apply the style

```
<style TargetType="local:CustomButton">
    <!-- Setters -->
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong? I add the CustomButton programmatically, is this the problem? I tried the following as well:

```
CustomButton customButton = new CustomButton();
customButton.Style = FindResource("<key>");
someGrid.Children.Add(customButton);
```

Comment: Please read what the description of the tag [coding-style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) says and take the appropriate action.

Comment: if I remember correctly, I had the tag "Style" set, is this the same as coding-style?

Comment: Hi Dänu, [coding style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style) refers to the style in which programmers write program. Styling of the UIs, CSS, skins/themes are a different subject altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomButton}"`

Edit:

> WPF supports techniques that enable
>   specifying the value of some
>   properties of type Type without
>   requiring an x:Type markup extension
>   usage. Instead, you can specify the
>   value as a string that names the type.
>   Examples of this are
>   ControlTemplate.TargetType and
>   Style.TargetType. Support for this
>   behavior is not provided through
>   either type converters or markup
>   extensions. Instead, this is a
>   deferral behavior implemented through
>   FrameworkElementFactory.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx)